# Create index with the same name as request path value, using ElasticSearch output

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

This is my `logstash.conf`:

```
input {
    http {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 31311 
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]      
  }
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

As a test, I ran this command in PowerShell:

> C:\Users\Me\Downloads\curl-7.64.1-win64-mingw\bin> .\curl.exe -XPUT
>   'http://127.0.0.1:31311/twitter'

The following output was displayed inside my `Logstash` terminal:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2019-04-09T08:32:09.250Z,
       "message" => "",
      "@version" => "1",
       "headers" => {
           "request_path" => "/twitter",
           "http_version" => "HTTP/1.1",
        "http_user_agent" => "curl/7.64.1",
         "request_method" => "PUT",
            "http_accept" => "*/*",
         "content_length" => "0",
              "http_host" => "127.0.0.1:31311"
    },
          "host" => "127.0.0.1"
}
```

When I then ran

> C:\Users\Me\Downloads\curl-7.64.1-win64-mingw\bin> .\curl.exe -XGET
>   "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices"

inside PowerShell, I saw

`yellow open logstash-2019.04.09  1THStdPfQySWl1WPNeiwPQ 5 1      0  0    401b    401b`

An index named `logstash-2019.04.09` has been created in response to my `PUT` request, following the ElasticSearch [convention](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index).

My question is: If I want the index to have the same value as the `{index_name}` parameter I pass inside the the command `.\curl.exe -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:31311/{index_name}'`, how should I configure the ElasticSearch output inside my `logstash.conf` file?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I want `{index_name}` to be read dynamically every single time I make a `PUT` request to create a new index. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with the [index output configuration option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index).
This configuration can be dynamic using the `%{foo}` syntax. Since you want the value of `[headers][request_path]` to be in the index configuration, you can do something like this:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"] 
    index => "%{[headers][request_path]}"     
  }
}
```

For this to work the value `[headers][request_path]` field must not contain any of these characters: `[ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]`.
I recommend that you use the [gsub configuration option of the mutate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub). So, to remove all the forward slashes, you should have something like this:

```
filter{
  mutate{
      gsub => ["[headers][request_path]","/",""]
    }
}
```

If the request path has several forward slashes, you could replace them with some character that will be accepted by elasticsearch.
So, your **final** logstash.conf file should look like this:

```
input {
    http {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 31311 
    }
}

filter{
  mutate{
      gsub => ["[headers][request_path]","/",""]
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[headers][request_path]}"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, toomaas! ``gsub`` is unfortunately not appropriate, because if my ``request_path`` is ``/twitter/1``, then the resulting string would be ``twitter1``. I am thinking of splitting ``request_path`` on ``/`` instead, so that I can add the fields ``index_id`` (corresponding to the first item) and ``document_id`` (corresponding to the second item). Do you know how I can check the length of the resulting array after splitting on ``/``?

Comment: To check the array length of a split field, a ruby filter will have to be used. So, for example, if you want to save the length of the array in an event variable you could do something like this: `ruby {
  code => "event.set('request_path_length', event.get('[headers][request_path]').length)"
}`. Then you can use the `%{request_path_length}` syntax to access the value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have posted a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590889/invalid-fieldreference-occurred-when-attempting-to-create-index-with-the-same-na Will you kindly take a look and enlighten me on what I did wrong? I feel like I am going nuts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding an `index` configuration setting to your elasticsearch output section. e.g.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"] 
    index => "yourindexnamehere"     
  }
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Correct me if I am wrong, but your approach does not allow the index to be read dynamically every time I make a ``PUT`` request, which is what I want to achieve. Is that even possible to configure?

Comment: Instead of `yourindexnamehere` use `%{[headers][request_path]}`

Comment: @Val Thanks for your reply. I made your suggested change, but unfortunately I saw the error message ``"Invalid index name [/twitter], must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]"``, because ``request_path`` is ``/twitter``. How can I remove the ``/``?

Comment: Oh right, we need to add a filter to remove that initial slash character

Comment: @Val I know how to remove all ``/``, but what if I only want to remove the first occurrence? If I send another ``PUT`` request to ``/twitter/1``, I don't want the second ``/`` to be removed.

Comment: Yes, you want because the index name must only be `twitter` and not `twitter/1`... we probably need to explode the request path in order to reuse all the path components in your elasticsearch output. I'll provide an answer after lunch.

Comment: Rather than strip the leading `/` could try using the `split` operator to split on `/`. Then take the item at index `[1]` in the resulting array, that should be the index name

Comment: @kjr I am thinking of using this approach as well. Just to confirm, the index name is located at index ``[1]`` and not ``[0]``?

Comment: I haven't tested, but i'd assumed index `[0]` would be an empty string (in front of the first slash)

Comment: @kjr Additionally, will Logstash crash if I try to access an invalid index? Let's say I split on ``/``, but I do not know the length of the resulting array. What happens if I try to access an item at an index that is out of bounds?