# Invalid FieldReference occurred when attempting to create index with the same name as request path value using ElasticSearch output

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

This is my `logstash.conf` file:

```
input {
    http {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 31311 
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        split => ["%{headers.request_path}", "/"]
        add_field => { "index_id" => "%{headers.request_path[0]}" }
        add_field => { "document_id" => "%{headers.request_path[1]}" }
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "%{index_id}"
    document_id => "%{document_id}"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

When I send a `PUT` request like

> C:\Users\BolverkXR\Downloads\curl-7.64.1-win64-mingw\bin> .\curl.exe
>   -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:31311/twitter'

I want a new index to be created with the name `twitter`, instead of using the ElasticSearch [default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index).

However, Logstash crashes immediately with the following (truncated) error message:

> Exception in pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new
>   events, please check your filter configuration and restart Logstash.
>   org.logstash.FieldReference$IllegalSyntaxException: Invalid
>   FieldReference: `headers.request_path[0]`

I am sure I have made a syntax error somewhere, but I can't see where it is. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

The same error occurs when I change the `filter` segment to the following:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        split => ["%{[headers][request_path]}", "/"]
        add_field => { "index_id" => "%{[headers][request_path][0]}" }
        add_field => { "document_id" => "%{[headers][request_path][1]}" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split the field the `%{foo}` syntax **is not used**. Also you should start at position [1] of the array, because in position [0] there will be an empty string(`""`) due to the reason that there are no characters at the left of the first separator(`/`). Instead, your filter section should be something like this:

```
 filter {
    mutate {
        split => ["[headers][request_path]", "/"]
        add_field => { "index_id" => "%{[headers][request_path][1]}" }
        add_field => { "document_id" => "%{[headers][request_path][2]}" }
    }
}
```

You can now use the value in `%{index_id}` and `%{document_id}`. I tested this using `logstash 6.5.3` version and used Postman to send the 'http://127.0.0.1:31311/twitter/1' HTTP request and the output in console was as follows:

```
{
        "message" => "",
       "index_id" => "twitter",
    "document_id" => "1",
       "@version" => "1",
           "host" => "127.0.0.1",
     "@timestamp" => 2019-04-09T12:15:47.098Z,
        "headers" => {
             "connection" => "keep-alive",
           "http_version" => "HTTP/1.1",
            "http_accept" => "*/*",
          "cache_control" => "no-cache",
         "content_length" => "0",
          "postman_token" => "cb81754f-6d1c-4e31-ac94-fde50c0fdbf8",
        "accept_encoding" => "gzip, deflate",
           "request_path" => [
            [0] "",
            [1] "twitter",
            [2] "1"
        ],
              "http_host" => "127.0.0.1:31311",
        "http_user_agent" => "PostmanRuntime/7.6.1",
         "request_method" => "PUT"
    }
}
```

The output section of your configuration does not change. So, your final logstash.conf file will be something like this:

```
input {
    http {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 31311 
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        split => ["[headers][request_path]", "/"]
        add_field => { "index_id" => "%{[headers][request_path][1]}" }
        add_field => { "document_id" => "%{[headers][request_path][2]}" }
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "%{index_id}"
    document_id => "%{document_id}"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```